# Creating multiple files and linking them in C

Tags: c, linux, command-line-interface

I am using C with Linux cc Compiler. What I want to do is create a main.c file which contains the main function. I want to create also a Special.c file which does not have a main function, instead it has only Special functions that I want to call in my main.c whenever needed.

I have more practice of Java, e.g. in Java I would just create two classes and use inheritance for this purpose.

But as I am new to C I am not sure how to do it. I know there might be a way of using .h files along with a library but I am not sure how to go about it here.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The search term for what you want to do is **separate compilation**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose special.c looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void special_func()
{
    printf("calling special_func\n");
}
```

You can then compile this file by itself:

```
gcc -c special.c
```

This generates special.o.  Then suppose you have this for main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "special.h"

int main()
{
    printf("in main\n");
    special_func();
    return 0;
}
```

Your `main` function calls `special_func`, however it is not defined in this file, so it needs to know how to call it.  That's where the contents of special.h come in:

```
#ifndef SPECIAL_H
#define SPECIAL_H

void special_func();

#endif
```

This is a **function prototype**.  It declares the function (i.e. tells you the number and types of the arguments, and the return type) without actually defining it.  This allows it to be called from other compilation units.

So now you can compile main.c by itself:

```
gcc -c main.c
```

This creates main.o.  Now you can link then together:

```
gcc -o program main.o special.o
```

Answer (score 0):

i will show you by example:

main.c is the file that has your main function.

helper.h has all the declarations for the functions you want to use in your main function.
helper.c has the definitions.

now, technically you can have your function definitions in helper.h but that is not good practice.

you then need to have :

```
#include "helper.h"
```

on top of your main.c program. 
finally you need to compile all of the .c files together.

like: gcc main.c helper.c -o output

```
//main.c:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <helper.h>
int main()
{
int squareMe=5;
squareMe = helperFn(squareMe);
printf("%d", squareMe);

}
```

now this is in your helper.h:

```
int helperFn(int input); //only function declaration
```

finally in helper.c:

```
#include "helper.h"

int helperFn(int i)
{
 return i*i;
}
```